# Using tapply to get means of different columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, tapply

So for an assignment I have to put 3 normal distributions in a dataframe, and then calculate 3 means by using 'tapply'. I have no idea why this is giving me a lot of values instead of just 1 mean.

Can anyone help me out?

```
x <- seq(1,100)
s1 <- dnorm(x, mean = 61, sd = 63)
s2 <- dnorm(x, mean = 38, sd = 5)
s3 <- dnorm(x, mean = 355, sd = 58)

df <- data.frame(s1,s2,s3)

means <- tapply(df$s1, df$s1, mean)
```

Comment: Is this just `colMeans(df)`?

Comment: You want to use `rnorm()` and not `dnorm()` to generate the list of random numbers. For 100 normally distributed numbers: `norm(100, mean = 61, sd = 63)`

Answer (score 1):

Solved this chaning the data format to long

```
df <- data.frame(x,s1,s2,s3) %>%
        pivot_longer(cols = -x)

value <- df$value
name <- df$name

means <- tapply(value, name, mean)

means
```

## Output

```
          s1           s2           s3 
5.662221e-03 1.000000e-02 5.719782e-08
```